# XMPP chat app got rejected for using VoIP service as background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, chat, voip

I Have done a XMPP chat app in which I am using Voip service for getting the Voip key in order to recieve the chat message when I am in background. The functionality all worked fine but the app store is rejecting the app with a response as given below:

> **2.16: Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.**
>
> 2.16
>   We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for VoIP in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not provide any Voice over IP services.
>
> We recognize that VoIP can provide "keep alive" functionality that many app features would like to use. However, using VoIP in this manner is not the intended purpose of VoIP, which, as indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide, is that: "A Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) application allows the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection instead of the device's cellular service."
>
> It would be appropriate to add VoIP features or remove the "VoIP" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:
>
> - complete details of your rejection issue(s)
> - screenshots
> - steps to reproduce the issue(s)
> - symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/TechnicalQ&A QA1764: How to reproduce a crash or bug that only App Review or users are seeing.

I need a strong answer from someone so that I can get the functionality to work fine and also be approved for the App Store.

I think the rejection is happening after the release of iOS 7. I need some assistance from someone who has uploaded a XMPP chat app after the release of iOS 7

Comment: [The tag wiki for the app-store tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/app-store/info) states that questions related to App Store rejections are considered to be off-topic.

Comment: Hello Dipin, if you have got any solution for this question please share it..

Answer (score 4):

You can't just add `voip` flag and get approved by Appstore, you need to implement VOIP functionality or you will be rejected. Most XMPP applications in Appstore does not work in background, but some of them implements VOIP over [Jingle](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html) and get approved with `voip` flag.

On the other hand, if your application stick to your XMPP server, you can modify server behaviour - stay user session online even if he disconnected, manage received messages and notify user about it via Apple Push Notifications. Then user launch app, resume previous session and get all stored messages. This behaviour not yet standartized, but there is some [work-in-progress specification](http://legastero.github.io/customxeps/extensions/push.html).

Comment: I need the voip service in order to make the socket work in background. Is there any othe method for making the socket work in background.

Comment: I am using local notification to alert the user if he is in background. The local notification will be triggered in the xmppdidrecievemessage: method. I am not disconnecting/goOffline the server even  if i went background.

Comment: Hello Dipin, if you have got any solution for this question please share it..i have same problem..please