# PushKit: Can we use push kit(VoiP Push) in Chat Application without using VoiP

Tags: ios, push-notification, background-process, pushkit

I want to sync my local DB with server when Push notification came, but I am not able to do it with Silent Notification because application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler not called when app killed by user. So, I did not know how to do it, then I read about push kit but don't know is it possible to use push kit without VoiP feature. Please tell me is it possible or not??
If not, suggest me any other idea , how will I run background task when app killed by user??

Comment: Did you used PK and got it into the store? We have a similar requirement and still no solution. We tried using the new PushNotificationExtension to overcome the problem with a killed app but then there is no way to suppress incoming notifications being displayed (e.g. silent-notification).

Answer (score 3):

In my experience as well as others on SO - you get rejected for trying to leverage VOIP as a workaround. See below for actual response from apple dealing with a similar [attempt.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756142/xmpp-chat-app-got-rejected-for-using-voip-service-as-background-mode)

2.16: Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.

2.16 We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

We noticed your app declares support for VoIP in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not provide any Voice over IP services.

We recognize that VoIP can provide "keep alive" functionality that many app features would like to use. However, using VoIP in this manner is not the intended purpose of VoIP, which, as indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide, is that: "A Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) application allows the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection instead of the device's cellular service."

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the only way to restart the app when it was killed by user is to use PushKit.
It is possible to use PK framework in your app without Voip functionality, but I can't guarantee you, that your app will not be banned while posting to AppStore.